# Error: ngModel: Non-Assignable Expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have code which generates drop down list dynamically. I want to set selected value using ng-repeat, to do this i am using function in ng-model but i am getting

```
Error: [ngModel:nonassign] Expression 'item.blockName = getCurrentComboBoxValue(item.blockName.id, blockNameOptions)' is non-assignable. Element: <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="item.blockName = getCurrentComboBoxValue(item.blockName.id, blockNameOptions)" name="blockName" ng-options="choice.id as choice.value for choice in blockNameOptions">
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in modulesData.blocks track by item.id">
    <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="item.blockName = getCurrentComboBoxValue(item.blockName.id, blockNameOptions)" name="blockName" 
        ng-options="choice.id as choice.value for choice in blockNameOptions">

    </select>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.getCurrentComboBoxValue = function (id, availableData) {
    var result = _.where(availableData, { 'id': id });
    return result[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`getCurrentComboBoxValue(blockNameOptions)` is not valid on the left-hand side of an `=`. ngModel requires that the thing on the left-hand side is assignable.

Comment: :I have edited my code (listed in question) but still i am getting same error.

Comment: You're misunderstanding. The thing you put in ngModel needs to be assignable--not an assignment itself. Think about it this way: your expression in ngModel is going to be pasted into something that looks like this: `? = valueFromInput;`. The `?` is your expression. You can't put `getCurrentComboBoxValue(item.blockName.id, blockNameOptions)` in that spot, because it's not a valid left-hand value. Same goes for what you updated it to.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do what angular does for you.  If you give angular a "name" of a property to assign the selected value to it will automatically bind the value. when it changes.  In your case the selectedValue would be `choice.id`.  This value can either be an existing thing on scope, or it will assign it to scope.  So for example:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in modulesData.blocks track by item.id">
    <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="selectedItem" name="blockName" 
    ng-options="choice.id as choice.value for choice in blockNameOptions">

    </select>
    <div>I selected  {{selectedItem}}</div>
</div>
```

and in your Ctrl you could do

```
$scope.getCurrentComboBoxValue = function (id, availableData) {
    console.log($scope.selectedItem);
}
```

If you would have defaulted $scope.selectedBlock =  , it would have defaulted the select for you.